# OpenProcessToken fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED from a local system service

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, antivirus

Let me explain my situation first. The issue I describe below comes from an end-user's machine, and all I have to work with is just a copy of the Windows Event Log. I cannot access the machine itself to run any debugging tests.

Now the issue. I have a service application that I create as such:

```
SC_HANDLE hScService = CreateService(hScManager, 
    L"MyServiceID", 
    L"My Service Name",
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, 
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, 
    SERVICE_AUTO_START, 
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
    SrvcPath,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, _T(""));
```

The service process later has its `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege set using the `AdjustTokenPrivileges` API.

Later on I have a method that enumerates running processes and later gets processes LUIDs, using a code as such:

```
//'pProcIDs' = list of process IDs obtained from EnumProcesses()

for(UINT i = 0; i < nNumProc; i++)
{
    DWORD dwProcID = pProcIDs[i];

    //Skip obvious system processes
    if(dwProcID != 0 &&
        dwProcID != 4)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcID);
        if(hProcess)
        {
            HANDLE hTokenHandle;
            if(::OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hTokenHandle))
            {
                TOKEN_STATISTICS ts;
                DWORD dwcbSz = 0;
                if(::GetTokenInformation(hTokenHandle, TokenStatistics, &ts, sizeof(ts), &dwcbSz))
                {
                    //And so on...
                }
                else
                {
                    //Handle error here
                }

                ::CloseHandle(hTokenHandle);
            }
            else
            {
                //***Here's where I get my error in question***
            }

            ::CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
        else
        {
            //Handle error here
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code above on my own development computers, it runs just fine. *Note that those computers run "stock" copies of the OS without any AVP or other third-party software installed.*

The event log copy I received from a customer running Windows 7 Professional machine (that is a member of an Active Directory domain) has 3 processes that return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when I call `OpenProcessToken` on them from the code above. Their PIDs are just regular values, such as 1824, 2760, 5024 (that obviously change after a reboot.)

Does anyone have any idea why it happens? Do I need to set additional privileges for my service?

PS. From the event log I can tell that the workstation in question has some `Symantec Antivirus` product installed, judging by this line:

> New virus definition file loaded. Version: 140217066.

Comment: Oh lord, an access rights issue. Your call to OpenProcessToken is (in effect) asking for access to information about the other process. It is failing because it does not have this level of access rights to these processes - maybe they are running with a higher level of privilege within the domain. If you look at the doc on OpenProcessToken and examine the dwAccess parameter, it will lead you into the intricacies of access rights. The first thing to do, however, is to call GetLastError when it fails & log the result somehow so you have a better idea what the problem is.

Comment: @TimBergel: I think I indicated above that the error I get is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. So what shall I use in the `dwAccess` parameter?

Comment: sorry failed to read carefully. This is the hard bit (I would try Bukes answer first BTW). The doc on OpenProcessToken says: "Specifies an access mask that specifies the requested types of access to the access token. These requested access types are compared with the discretionary access control list (DACL) of the token to determine which accesses are granted or denied.

For a list of access rights for access tokens, see Access Rights for Access-Token Objects.", but it says nothing about how to set the value. I think TOKEN_QUERY is very probably correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symantec antivirus software (as well as that of many other security software vendors) may attempt to prevent tampering with their processes by un-authorized actors.  Acquiring the process token for one of their processes just might qualify.

That said, you can quickly verify that the PIDs in question are in fact part of the Symantec package by examining the path to executable images that back the processes.  If they are part of the Symantec AV software package, you'll need to look in to configuring it to trust your application, or disable it while you run this code (not recommended), or simply ignore errors of this type.

Comment: you can use `GetModuleFileNameEx()` to get the filename of an external process. You already have the HANDLE to it. `GetModuleFileNameEx()` needs both `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` and `PROCESS_VM_READ` rights, though.

Comment: @Bukes: Is AVP really allowed to modify behavior of system APIs?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Hmm. This means that I will need to open the process with more access rights that I actually need. Still, even if I get a process path, what can I do with it? I can put it in the log... that's  pretty much it.

Comment: The reason I collect process tokens is to see if the process is still running. I need to do this before a user logs out. So if I can't accomplish this, my overall method will fail.

Comment: @Randy Lebeau - The better way to acquire the image path is via GetProcessImageFileName(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you want to be notified on process exit, you might be able to open the process object with the SYNCHRONIZE flag and wait on the returned handle - it'll become signaled when the process exits.

Comment: @Bukes: Well, that's not that easy. I need to monitor all processes for a user. Also, why would I want to adjust to Norton? My first question still remains -- Is AVP allowed to modify behavior of system APIs?

Comment: Allowed? Absolutely. Microsoft publishes kernel Apis that security software vendors can use to extend the security model of the operating system.

Comment: OK. If it's the kernel filter that AVP uses to control `OpenProcessToken` behavior then there's no privileges that will let my service retrieve the token. Oh, that $%^# Norton!

Comment: The "higher privilege" your code needs in this case is to be running in kernel mode, though of course this may or may not be appropriate depending on the purpose of the application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yeah, I got that. What PO's me the most is that some 3rd party vendors like Symantec are dictating the operation of the OS APIs. Found this by accident, it pretty much shows what most people think about Norton: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=norton+antivirus

Comment: @c00000fd Out of curiosity, what is the overall problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Bukes: Let's see if I can explain it in constraints of this little window. My service has a function to put workstation into sleep mode when all interactive users are logged off from  it. My first gut reaction was to use WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF notifications. Unfortunately if I send workstation to sleep right after the service receives WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF notification for the last user, it will totally "mess up" the user logon process. One way to fix this situation was to make my service wait for all processes previously running for the interactive user to quit. Thus the need for the code above...

Comment: @c00000fd That doesn't sound like you need to ubiquitously monitor all processes. Instead, when it comes time, open a process handle to all running processes with the `SYNCHRONIZE` flag, and `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: Are there really processes still running in the session when you receive WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF?  I ran into a very similar issue a while back, and my interpretation was that Windows was in a transition state where certain operations were unsafe, unrelated to what user processes might or might not still be running.  I would expect issuing the call from a different thread after a delay of a few seconds to resolve the problem.  In any case, it should be safe to ignore the protected processes in this context.

Comment: Looking at my old code it appears I resolved the issue by listening for CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT instead of WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF.  IIRC, attempting to reboot or power down during WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF handling caused problems, but worked fine during CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT handling.  That was a while back, but it may be worth a try.